# How to securely place API keys or salts in Android?

Tags: android, android-security

I was wondering what should be an ideal way for placing API keys, salts, or even private keys for encryption and ship them along with the APK. While doing research on this I saw a couple of methods widely used for placing some of these details:-

1. **Place this info in gradle.properties** - This is the simplest solution for placing these details but it is not secure at all. The information stored here can easily be extracted from the APK.
2. **Store it in cpp** - Create CPP files in the codebase where these details are placed and write JNIs to extract out these details when needed. This makes it harder for the attacker to extract out these details but it still is extractable

I read a couple of posts of which recommended using **Keystore** for securely storing this information but while seeing implementation at a couple of places I inferred that it usually stores values in runtime and I didn’t find any details on how to ship some salts or API keys along with the APK.
I wanted to know if there is any way for securely placing salts, API keys, etc along with the shipped APK. Or we can somehow use Keystore for this. Any help or suggestion will be really appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: I always store my key in cpp . What is the problem with it??

Comment: @elhamdabiri You can see this article for details. https://rammic.github.io/2015/07/28/hiding-secrets-in-android-apps/

Answer (score 0):

Using this library You can easily secaure your api

https://github.com/MEiDIK/Cipher.so

Read Carefully there installation Process and still have any doubts  or error  i will help you